# how to include previous generated WHILE content in an output template

Tags: php

I'm generating dynamic content from a database like this:

```
$sql_select_items = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE ...);
```

Then it pulls the results, which may be one or multiple, like this:

```
while ($item_details = $db->fetch_array($sql_select_items))
            {

                $items_content = 
                    '<table><tr> '.
                    '<td>RETRIEVED CONTENT HERE</td> '.
                    '</tr></table>';
            }
```

Then, further down, I am outputting the generated content like this:

```
   if ($section == 'summary_main')
    {
        $summary_page_content['content'] = 

            $summary_page_content['details'] . 
            $items_content .  
            $summary_page_content['messaging_received'] .
            $summary_page_content['footer']
            ;

        $template->set('members_area_page_content', $summary_page_content['content']);

    }
```

Everything works except for the content generated by $items_content , which only displays 1 item no matter if there are 1 or 20. I tried to do a

```
$items_content . =
```

instead of

```
$items_content =
```

but that didn't seem to work either and just gave me an error.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not `$db->fetch_array($sql_select_items)` it's `$sql_selected_items->fetch_array()`. Here's how I would do it:

```
$table_rows = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE ...");
if($table_rows->num_rows > 0){
  $table = '<table><tbody>';
  while($row = $table_rows->fetch_object()){
    $table .= "<tr><th>{$row->title_column_name}</th><td>{$row->other_column_name}</td></tr>";
  }
  $table .= '</tbody></table>';
}
else{
  $table = '';
  // no results
}
echo $table;
$table_rows->free(); $db->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Outside of (before) the while loop:

```
$items_content = '';
```

Inside the while loop:

```
$items_content .= '...';
```

This will make sure that your `$items_content` variable exists before your loop, and then the `.=` will concatenate your string to the end of `$items_content`.

**"What am I doing wrong?"**

As you didn't post the error, I can only assume you either got an undefined variable notice, which is solved by placing `$items_content = '';` before the loop, or your got a syntax error because the operator you should be using is `.=` and not `. =` (note that the space is wrong).

Comment: Tried that but I'm getting a syntax error saying unexpected '='

Comment: Does it give you a line number? Can you post the offending line? Are you sure there is no space between your `.` and your `=`?